# Create db and load files (npm stardog)

Tags: npm, rdf, stardog

We Have an issue to create a new db (npm stardog). we try to load files into the db, but we get an empty db without a file, we think the problem is in

-> option.({files: {filename:string}[]}) so We add our code to show how we try to load the files.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGTK0.png)

This is the documentation for db.create()

[db.creat documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llhct.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what errors?..just a small picture from my code